# Cannot allow only particular IP Address access my website with apache 2.4

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I'd like to define whitelist IPs (myIP1, myIP2) in VHOST file to allow only particular IP Addresses access my website in apache 2.4. I've tried with several ways but it's work is not as my expected. What I've tried:

**1. The First**

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html/website">
    <RequireAny>
       Require ip myIP1
       Require ip myIP2
    </RequireAny>
 </Directory>
```

**Result:** I can access the site from everywhere not only particular IPs

**2. The Second**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/website">
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
   Require all denied
   Require ip myIP1
   Require ip myIP2
</Directory>
```

**Result:** I can access the site from everywhere not only particular IPs.

**3. The Third**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/website">
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from myIP1
   allow from myIP2
</Directory>
```

**Result:** I cannot access the site from everywhere even from myIP1 or myIP2.

This is my `.htacess`

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Could someone can tell me what I'm wrong? And help me correct it.
Thanks.

Comment: With Apache 2.4 the first one should work. Can you show what entries appear in your access log when you use that

Comment: This is my access.log
`162.158.79.128 - - [18/May/2017:07:43:55 +0000] "POST /users/test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 517 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
162.158.79.128 - - [18/May/2017:07:44:10 +0000] "POST /users/test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 517 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
162.158.79.128 - - [18/May/2017:07:44:13 +0000] "POST /users/test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 517 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
`

Comment: This is my error.log
`[authz_core:debug] [pid 50317] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 162.158.179.139:27039] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: denied
[authz_core:debug] [pid 50317] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 162.158.179.139:27039] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
[authz_core:error] [pid 50317] [client 162.158.179.139:27039] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/abtesting/public/users`

Comment: presumably the ip address in the access log/error log is the one that you're `Require`-ing in the config? Can you show exactly how you're specifying it in the config?

Comment: `<RequireAny>
       Require ip 54.157.2.251
       Require ip 54.175.187.177
    </RequireAny>`

Comment: But I don't know why when I access the website from `54.157.2.251`, I see the log that is `162.158.79.128`, not is `54.157.2.251`

Comment: Is your website using any kind of load balancer, or caching proxy?

Comment: I'm using EC2 and it's not kind of load balancer or caching proxy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144544/discussion-between-stephen-and-charles-pham).

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it with Apache 2.4

### 1. **To Allow only IPs List or once**

```
<Directory  "/var/YourSite/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
        Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
    </Directory>
```

### 2. **To Allow from Everywhere**

```
<Directory  "/var/YourSite/">
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
```